# What is the emberjs way for the use case: one route (router v2) but two models should be displayed?

Tags: ember.js, routes, ember-data

I have used emberjs with router v2 for some use cases and it works really good. I have no problems with use cases in which the complexity of a page grow through clicking on {{linkto ..}} constructs (with related nested resources).

But some times it could be necessary to be able to display two (or more) different models at once.

For example:

I have the model Person and the Model Pet.

Something like:

```
 DS.RESTAdapter.configure("plurals",{"person" : "people"})

 App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
revision: 11,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({namespace: 'restservice'})
 });

 var attr = DS.attr;

 App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
firstName: attr('string'),
lastName: attr('string'),
birthDay: attr('string'),
    pets: DS.hasMany('App.Pet')
 });


App.Pet = DS.Model.extend({
  name: attr('string'),
  species: attr('string'),
  person: DS.belongsTo('App.Person')
});
```

For some reason instances of Model Person and Pet exists but the relation between these two models are not defined yet.

In a page, which is called through an {{linkto ..}} construct I want implement a
person - pet assignment editor.
In this case I want display two lists:

- a list of people
- a list of pets

Normally the route for this page would correspond only to one model but for the person - pet assigment editor it would be completely natural that both models should be displayed at once (without additional user intervention).

What is the best way to implement that.
Should I  load the models without the routing concept ?

Does exist a way like this:

```
      (represent the person - pet assigment editor 'page')
                         |
                         |
```

{{linkto ..}} -------> resource-route  -----> 'splitting redirect'

```
                                          - ----------------> resource-route  person

                                          - ----------------> resource-route  pet


   (like a url to a frame set which bear two (or more) 'parallel' requests)
```

After the splitting redirect I have 3 active routes:

- resource-route for  person - pet assigment editor
- resource-route  person
- resource-route  pet

After that, normal incremental drilldown (deeper nesting routes: selecting a person,  selecting a pet ..)  actions could be take place.

I can implement my use case without such a concept but I like the routing concept and be interested in using it in more complex scenarios.

Does exist a concept like this ?
What is the emberjs way to deal with such scenarios ?

Best regards

Andreas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that the *splitting redirect* is the right idea. You are taking the router too far - this will make matters more complicated than they need to be. I suggest that you make a route for *person-pet* assignment and just display pets and persons there. The models for this route will be all relevant pets and persons - still 2 kinds of models. I don't know the proper way to specify 2 models in `model` method, thus i suggest to load them in `setupController`:

```
App.PetsToPersonRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    setupController: function (controller) {
        controller.setProperties({
            pets: App.Pet.find(),
            persons: App.Person.find()
        });
    }
});
```